# How to import images from Picasso

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import, picasso

I'm writing an app as a learner based on an android development book. In the book, the author wrote some certain codes that prove to be efficient but based on the fact that it was written in 2015, some features have changed on the recent android documentations.

My adapter.java code issued an error on the .into(imageView) part and if I click alt + enter, the suggestions they give me are: Create local variable 'imageView', and some others but none of those seem to solve the issue.

Adapter.java code below:

```
package com.dummies.tasks.adapter;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.dummies.tasks.activity.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class TaskListAdapter
extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskListAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
static String[] fakeData = new String[] {
"One",
"Two",
"Three",
"Four",
"Five",
"Ah . . . ah . . . ah!"
};

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
// create a new view
CardView v = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
.inflate(R.layout.card_task, parent, false);
// wrap it in a ViewHolder
return new ViewHolder(v);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
viewHolder.titleView.setText(fakeData[i]);

// set the thumbnail image
Picasso.get().load("http://lorempixel.com/600/400/cats/?fakeId=").into(imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return fakeData.length;
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { 
CardView cardView;
TextView titleView;
ImageView imageView;

public ViewHolder(CardView card) {
super(card);
cardView = card;
titleView = card.findViewById(R.id.text1);
imageView = card.findViewById(R.id.image);
}
}
}
```

When I first ran the code without Picasso, it ran without error but importing from Picasso is the issue.

I also included `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in android manifest.xml

The app should look like this when it's done: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVSJZ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put viewHolder.imageView like that
Picasso.get().load("http://lorempixel.com/600/400/cats/?fakeId=").into(viewHolder.imageView);

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2

Picasso.with(context).load(image_url).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(imageView);

Comment: Didn't fix with this plus the latest Picasso version is 2.71828 not 2.5.2 but thanks